# HDD partition corrupting

Tags: raid, partition, corruption

I manage a server for a nursing home. The system is running 3 x 320GB SAS drives in a RAID5 array. This is split into 6 partitions. The partition which stores all the users profiles becomes corrupt every few months. Write caching is disabled on the card as it has no battery. All of the hard drives have been replaced but this continues to occur. A chkdsk will fix it but only for a while. There is no power issues or anything interesting at the time this happens. Data will continue to corrupt until a chkdsk is run, after which its fine. Any other ideas of what else I can try? None of the other partitions have ever had any problems.

Comment: any chance of a LOT more information? You've told us nothing - not the machine, not the controller, disks, not even the operating system! come on, help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

User profiles can become corrupt due to many reasons, most of them are client-side. Are you sure your profile corruption doesn't start at the user's computer?

Also, is there any other file sharing going on with this server?

And is the server's anti-virus showing anything untoward? Maybe run some diagnostics on the anti-virus's I/O behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. :)
There is also administration files stored in the folder. This also becomes corrupt. Logging has showed that it is from no particular user. Even files which haven't been accessed for months have been lost. The data is locked down to only two users. When they were both on holidays this has occured.
The client side had occured to me. All system have checked out however. I was suspecting a rogue switch until i found the administrator profile losing files. This is only ever access locally, never from a client PC.
McAfee 8.7i is being used on the systems. It is showing nothing unusual within its log files. I will have a more thorough look at McAfee's logs in the meantime.